# Is it possible to re-write parts of an rss feed on the fly using php

Tags: php, rss

i have searched for a way to do this and can find none.

I am trying to find a way to convert rss feed on the fly. lets say i want to change all links in feed by find and replace "www.theirsite.com" TO "www.mynewsite.com"

So i would have a page on my site : mysite.com/convertrss.php
I would call my new rss from a url on my site something like this...

mysite.com/convertrss.php?www.theirsite.com/rss

Comment: What you say sounds pretty straigtforward. So, what's your question?

Comment: what would the php file convertrss.php look like ? it would need to call the rss,then rewrite parts of it and then be available as a new rss feed url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents of file ***convertrss.php*** depends on how big is source feed and what performance you want to achieve.

There are 2 solutions:

1.If source rss is relatively small (less then ~10MB) you can do it very simple:

```
<?php
$rssString = file_get_contents('www.theirsite.com/rss');
$rssConverted = str_replace('www.theirsite.com', 'www.mynewsite.com', $rssString );
echo $rssConverted;
//todo: also you might need to return proper RSS headers before "echo", if you RSS client needs it.
```

2.If source feed is big - you need to read and process it piece by piece. For example, with help of library [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).

Comment: `code` <?php
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$rssString = file_get_contents('site');
$rssConverted = str_replace('zazzle', 'podartist', $rssString );
echo $rssConverted;
//$site is a url parameter im trying to pass `code`       http://beachlux.com/convertrss.php?site=feed.zazzle.com/honorandobey/rss

Comment: Ok i got it working so thanks for your help, one small problem i need to replace all "-" i find in the GUID only how would I target just the GUID ? or better how to target anything contained in feed, image url, title,etc

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by GUID..
BTW, if your original question is resolved - you can mark helpful answer :)